# How to formt df columns in Python

Tags: python, format

```
data=[[0.101, 0.00223], [2.1203, 0.00456]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b'])
test= df.style.format(   {'a': "{:.2f}" ,   'b': "{:.2%} "}      )
```

I was expecting the output below, but it doesnt produce  any 
output (I'm using Spyder). No error message is produced.

a       b
0.10    0.22%
2.12    0.45%

Is there  a way to do this formatting in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the style to test.

```
data=[[0.101, 0.00223], [2.1203, 0.00456]] 

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b'])

df.style.format(   {'a': "{:.2f}" ,   'b': "{:.2%} "}      )
```

removing test produces the required output. or you just need to call test again at the end of the code.

Comment: I  run your code and add a command df at the end to call it, but the output is not formatted. In addition, I need the formatted df to be stored as a dataframe, so  I would  think I need something like  test= .....   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may try following. Please note that this is changing format on you raw data along with printing output.

```
data = [[0.101, 0.00223], [2.1203, 0.00456]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b'])
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x:round(x,2))
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x:'{:,.2f}%'.format(x*100))
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: works perfectly. How would I do if I want to format all the columns of the df with same format (say, all columns round(x,2) , without having to type one by one (I have too many columns...)?

Comment: @Rick, If you have other requirement other that what was asked then you can post it as new thread. You need to include your work (what you have done to achieve) along with any trouble for us to help you further.